# Why does Rust ops::add want me to implement `add` with a move?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and going through the Google course for exercises as I go through "the book", I'm on one of the [exercises](https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/exercises/day-2/points-polygons.html) and I am needing to implement the `+` operator. So I go to the docs and see [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#default-generic-type-parameters-and-operator-overloading) page on it and immediately wonder about the lack of ampersands in the args to `add` for the example, quoted below, [permalink to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=892bcb1e401fa5b73cfda56662690379)

```rust
pub struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

impl std::ops::Add<Point> for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(&self, b: &Point) -> Point {
        Self {
            x: self.x + b.x,
            y: self.y + b.y,
        }
    }
}
```

Why would I not expect that the arguments to `add` are immutable references instead of <del>borrows</del> moves? And it's not just the docs, the compiler wants it too,

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0053]: method `add` has an incompatible type for trait
 --> src/lib.rs:8:12
  |
8 |     fn add(&self, b: &Point) -> Point {
  |            ^^^^^
  |            |
  |            expected `Point`, found `&Point`
  |            help: change the self-receiver type to match the trait: `self`
  |
  = note: expected signature `fn(Point, Point) -> Point`
             found signature `fn(&Point, &Point) -> Point`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0053`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

Why might the creators of Rust enforce that addition (per it's usual definitions) design it this way? I imagine this works well for literals, but I believe that references would work for literals as well too. What am I missing?

Comment: Immutable references are borrows. If you want to add references, then you'd do `impl Add for &Point`.

Comment: I don't understand the comment "the compiler wants it to". The code in this question [compiles without any compiler or clippy messages](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2602dad4491b446e7837f0277daaba0).

Comment: @drewtato thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering why the suggestion in the book and from the compiler help did not have an ampersand since I _generally_ wouldn't want a `add` to mutate my arguments value or resources. If not a borrow of some kind, I supposed its a move. Is that right?

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks for pointing this out, I linked my code to the playground now

Comment: When it's this way, `String + &str` can reuse the `String` to avoid making an allocation. If it always took a reference, it would need to create a new `String` every time.

Comment: But to return String we'll need to make an allocation every time, and if we had &String, then we'd not be allowed to make mutations so it wouldn't need to allocate there either. I don't think I get the array views well enough, but I imagine it wouldn't need to allocate copies either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that `Add` has a somewhat hidden generic parameter; the full trait is

```rust
pub trait Add<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;

    // Required method
    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

The `Rhs` generic is `Self` by default, i.e., if unspecified. When you write `impl Add for Point` what you've actually written, implicitly, is `impl Add<Self> for Point`, where `Rhs=Self`. And then it's clear that the method you must implement is `add(self, rhs: Self)` (or `add(self, rhs: Point)`). Similarly if you write `impl Add for &Point` then you must implement `add(self, rhs: &Point)`. (Note that in this case, `self` is actually of type `&Point`, not `Point`, although you won't notice when everything is `Copy`.)

So you actually have four ways of implementing addition of `Point`s or `&Point`s here: `Add for Point` (aka `Add<Point> for Point`), `Add<&Point> for Point`, `Add for &Point` (aka `Add<&Point> for &Point`), and `Add<Point> for &Point`.

Comment: So the compiler is enforcing that Rhs to the `+` operator is of type Self. Thanks for clearing that up.

My other question (at end of post) is why would Add have this restriction and why would it be implemented without the immutable reference in the book? When might I want to change values or resources for something I call `add`? Alternatively, what silly mistake am I removing the possibility of by enforcing this?

Comment: Why is `rhs: Self` the default and not `rhs: &Self`? I'm guessing because the vast majority of things that are `Add` are `Copy` and it doesn't make a real difference but is more convenient. `Rhs` is just a defaulted generic, so you're free to set it to what you'd like. The question then is what's most convenient? They decided `Self` is a better default than `&Self`. You are free to implement `&Self` though.

Comment: Any thoughts as to why `Self` is a better default?

Answer (score 1):

yes it can be a little confusing at first, what I would recommend is to consider the `Point` type completely different from the `&Point` type, in this case you have implemented add for the `Point` type, **and that is fine**, but that is not what you wanted to do, in fact just do the same thing for the `&Point` type as well

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Add for &Point { //PAY ATTENTION HERE
    type Output = Point;

    fn add(self, other: &Point) -> Point { //AND HERE
        Point {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

fn main(){

    let point1 = Point{x: 1, y: 2};
    let point2 = Point{x: 1, y: 2};
    
    let point3 = point1.add(&point2);
    
    println!("{:?}", point1);
    println!("{:?}", point2);
    println!("{:?}", point3);
}
```

look at [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a84839001d3bf734c18caa1d02202078) to do some testing

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement it for both values and references:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Point;

    fn add(self, other: Point) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

impl Add<&Point> for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    #[inline]
    fn add(self, other: &Point) -> Point {
        self + *other
    }
}

impl Add<Point> for &Point {
    type Output = Point;
    #[inline]
    fn add(self, other: Point) -> Point {
        *self + other
    }
}

impl Add<&Point> for &Point {
    type Output = Point;
    #[inline]
    fn add(self, other: &Point) -> Point {
        *self + *other
    }
}
```

With this, you would be add references and values and do things like `points.iter().sum()`.